# Swagger UI custom order of endpoint parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

As we can see spring orders parameters by the name alphabetically.

[image]

I'd like to provide a custom order like in the @ApiModel class.

[image]

So fromLocation should be the last.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Springfox or springdoc?

Comment: i use Springfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible on Springfox and since the move to Java 8 it is alphabetically ordered:

> What we discovered when moving to java 8 compiler was that the order changed. When we realized that was the case, the parameters were changed to being alphabetically sorted

More details: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2418

Comment: Maybe it is possible with some custom implementations?

Comment: Maybe, but unfortunately, nothing is easy with Springfox.

Comment: If you are willing to give it a try, you can always consider moving to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). To be honest, I am not sure which sorting logic is used in this particular case, but if it is not what you are looking for you might open a ticket in their github page and request it or do it on your own and submit it for review.