# startDate comes before endDate in swagger Is there any way to preserve the order, or even specify the order

Tags: spring-boot, api, swagger, swagger-ui, http-request-parameters

**Actual Result:** endDate comes first then startDate comes next.

**Expected Result:** startDate comes first then endDate.

Is there any way to specify the requestParameter order?

[This is the Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTAkJ.png)

```java
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> getDetails(
    @NotEmpty(message = UIMessages.MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY) @RequestParam(
      value = "startDate") final String startDate,
    @NotEmpty(message = UIMessages.MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY) @RequestParam(
      value = "endDate") final String endDate,
final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
   //statements
}
```

[This is the swagger UI actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWlqz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger UI custom order of endpoint parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119337/swagger-ui-custom-order-of-endpoint-parameters)

Comment: Not get a proper solution. Is that because of moving on Java8 compiler is that order changed?